# Sava html attr in php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dom

I have list like this

```
John
   Jack (link)
       Husam (link)
   Koko (link)
       Rami (link)
       Loay (link)
```

and i have dropdown list that has all the names above, when i click on link Husam side i want to displayed his parent (Jack) as selected option in dropdown, so i need pass to function getParentId the id of child whose the link clicked, and this id inside , so how i can pass the attr name of  to  $_GET['childId'] instead of $_GET['childId'] = 4.
I try to save `attr` of link inside php variable.

Is it or is it not possible?

This is my code in `index.php`

```js
$_GET['childId'] = 4; // here i don't want to pass 4 i need to pass $(a).attr('name'); from another page
if ($object->getParentId($_GET['childId'])) {
  echo "<script>
  function changeParent(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('a').on('click',function() {
        var x = $(this).attr('id');
        var y = $(this).attr('name');
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'http://test.local/Family.php?action=getId',
          data: {'childId' : $_GET[childId]},
          success: function(msg) {
            document.getElementById('names').value = x;
            $('#save').show();
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }
  </script>";
}
```

This what I want to pass it in `Family.php` (the name of a href)

```js
function getChild($family_tree,$parent){
$list = "<ul class='listSet' style='list-style-type:none'>";
foreach($family_tree[$parent] as $each_child) {
  $list .= "<li>" . $each_child[0]."  "."<a  onclick='changeParent()' id='$parent' name='$each_child[1]' href='#'>".'Change parent'."</a>";
  if(isset($family_tree[$each_child[1]])){...
```

Comment: Don't you get an error at `oreach(` ?

Comment: Sorry i edited ... its mistake from copy past

Comment: I should to pass in getParentId($_GET['childId'])) the value of some attr in HTML  how i can do it ? if you want to describe you my case in details i can. :D @PhilippMaurer

Comment: @PhilippMaurer i edited my describe please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so in order to do it you have to make some changes in your functionality.

This condition `if ($object->getParentId($_GET['childId']))` you should move from `index.php` to `Family.php`

Next inside `$('a').on('click',function() {` change this line `data: {'childId' : $_GET[childId]},` to this `data: {'childId' : y},`

```js
function changeParent(){
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').on('click',function() {
      var x = $(this).attr('id');
      var y = $(this).attr('name');
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://test.local/Family.php?action=getId',
        data: {'childId' : y},
        success: function(msg) {
          document.getElementById('names').value = x;
          $('#save').show();
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```